# Не срабатывает картинка прозрачная на transparent navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, изображения, uitableview, navigationbar

подскажите в айфоне X не срабатывает прозрачный навигационный бар с статус баром.Почему залазит картинка на половину на статус бар.В общем корректно не срабатывает.Вот мой скриншот крепления и использую этот код.Раньше делал по другому через файл xib. Решил поменять методику и застрял.Буду очень благодарен добрым людям.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на других симуляторах проверяли? везде не срабатывают или только на Х

Comment: срабатывает везде, кроме айфона Х.Я переделал Хедер на xib файл.Теперь на всех девайсах не идет.((((((Помогите кто нибудь

Comment: Создай тестовый проект с твоей реализацией, а там уже постараюсь помочь чем смогу.

Comment: Так я так же самое делал в других разделах контроллерах и сработало.Не могу понять почему не идет тут.Все до детали выставил.